# How to extend button function on its container

Tags: jquery, sass

```
<div class="hotspot">
 <div class="productName">Bag</div>
 <div class="productPrice">20$</div>
 <button>Some action</button>
</div>
```

I need to extend the button function on all its container and hide it with opacity 0.

This is my code: https://codepen.io/andrew_88/pen/jemBgm.

I need to extend the function of my button on all the hotspot container and I want to hide it graphically (opacity: 0); I want to toggle the class "visible" only when I click on pseudo `:before` element (the red rectangle) and not when I click into the div (productName, productPrice, button). I can't find a solution for doing it.

Comment: Please include your code in the question.  Do only only link to it.

Comment: It's not clear what you exactly want to do. Also the pseudo elements are not a part of DOM so you can't listen o click events of pseudo elements.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question well, you want to have a click listener on the psuedo element which is not possible. You can simulate it by using click position.

```
(function() {
    $("article").each(function() {
        $(this)
            .children(".hotspot")
            .on("touchstart click", function(e) {
                var originalEvent = e.originalEvent;

                if ($(this).hasClass("visible")) {
                    if (originalEvent.layerX < 15 && originalEvent.layerY < 20) {
                        $(this).toggleClass("visible");
                    } else {
                        alert("ciao");
                    }
                } else if (originalEvent.layerX < 15 && originalEvent.layerY < 20) {
                    $(this).toggleClass("visible");
                }
            });
    });
    $(this).toggleClass("visible");

    // $("button").on("click", function() {
    //  alert("ciao");
    // });
})();
```

This is the working code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rqmwOX.
I just changed the JS part and also and I changed `min-width` to `width`.

Hope this helps